# Which of the following functions are continuous at every point of their respective domains?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

> Which of the following functions are continuous at every point of their respective domains of definition?
>
> (a) $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^2e^{nx}+x}{e^{nx}+1}$ , $x \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> (b) $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^2e^{nx}+\text{cos}x}{e^{nx}+1}$, $ x \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> (c) $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\text{log}(e^n+x^n)$, $x \ge 0$

My attempt:
(a) $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^2e^{nx}+x}{e^{nx}+1}=x^2\; \forall \;x$, so it is continuous.

(b) $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^2e^{nx}+\text{cos}x}{e^{nx}+1}=x^2$,$\forall x\neq 0$. But for fixed $x=0$, the limit is 1. Hence this is not continuous at $x=0$.

For case (c), I am unable to determine the limit.

I believe that this is not the correct way, please help me in solving the above question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding case $(c)$.

For $x>e$, you have $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\text{log}(e^n+x^n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\text{log}(x^n) = \log x$, and for $ 0 \le x \le e$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\text{log}(e^n+x^n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\text{log}(e^n) = 1$.

Therefore the limit function $f$ is also continuous in that case as $\lim\limits_{x \to e} \log x = 1$.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail why for $ x> e$ , $e^n+x^n$ changes to$x^n$ and similarly for $0\le x\le e$

Comment: I think $\lim\frac{1}{n} \log (e^n+x^n)=\lim\frac{1}{n} \log (e^n(1+(x/e)^n)=\lim\frac{1}{n} (\log (e^n)+\log (1+(x/e)^n))$ and it equals $\log(e)$ when $0 \le x \le e$, and similarly $\log(x)$ when $x \ge e$ (because you factor out $x^n$ instead of $e^n$)

Comment: @VIVID Indeed, for $0 \le x \le e$, it should have been log(e)=1. (you may treat as $ln$).

Comment: @s1mple You're right. I forgot the $\log$ and updated my answer.

Comment: Why would be the denominator be equal to $0$ when $n \to \infty$?

Comment: ohh sorry. It attains: 0*log(1) form. Thanks for the help!.

Answer (score 1):

Beware! In (a), if $x<0$, we have
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^2e^{nx}+x}{e^{nx}+1}=\frac{0+x}{0+1}.$$

More generally, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{nx}g(x)+h(x)}{e^{nx}+1} =\begin{cases}g(x)&x>0\\h(x)&x<0\\\frac{g(0)+h(0)}{2}&x=0\end{cases}$$

---

For (c), recall(?) that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n+1}=\begin{cases}x&x>1\\1&-1< x\le1\end{cases} $$

Comment: Oh,I didn't notice that. Thanks !!

Comment: Thanks for help. But I can't accept two answers. Sorry.